# Assigning concatenated array elements to a variable and validating with another array element

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, concatenation

The issue I'm having seems like it's because the concatenation of three elements of an array isn't the same thing as just the first element when the 2nd and 3rd elements are blank.

i.e.

element1.. != element1

not sure how to work around this as I need to compare the concatenated elements and have them work whether or not the last two elements exist

i.e.
$lineConcat should equal $line2[1] in this example:

```
$line = array(12345678,G,B,"abc",x);
$line2[1] = 12345678GB;

$lineConcat = $line[0].$line[1].$line[2];
```

$lineConcat should also equal $line2[2] in this example, but doesn't pass my if statement to check if the values are the same:

```
$line = array(12345678,,,"abc",x);
$line2[1] = 12345678;

$lineConcat = $line[0].$line[1].$line[2];

if ($line2[1]==$lineConcat) 
{
    $check=$line[1];
}
else
{
    $check="X";
}
```

This is always returning "X" for $check when the 2nd and third elements are blank, whether or not the first element alone is the same as $line[1].

Comment: When you say blank, do you mean empty strings? You can't just have commas sitting there in the array.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear.  The array would be more like $line = array(1234,,,abc,x).  My understanding is pretty amateur, when creating the array from a line of text there would be missing values for the array.

Comment: YOu cannot compare elements like that. consider two arrays that have `1,23,4` and `12,3,4`. Your concatenation will turn both into `1234` and test as equal, which is totally false.

Comment: That makes sense.  Should I test if the specific elements exist prior to comparison?